# RxSwift - doing control flow leads to async operation being performed twice

Tags: swift, macos, rx-swift, reactivex

Take a look at this example:

```
func query2() -> Observable<Int> {
    print("query2() called")
    return Observable.create { observer in
        print("creating query2() thread")
        let thread = Thread.init(block: {
            sleep(1)
            let numbers = [
                1,2,3,4,5
            ]
            for num in numbers {
                observer.onNext(num)
            }
            observer.onCompleted()
        })
        thread.start()
        return Disposables.create {
            thread.cancel()
        }
    }
}

let numbers = query2()
let even = numbers.filter { $0 % 2 == 0 }
let odd = numbers.filter { $0 % 2 != 0 }
let merged = even.concat(odd)

merged.subscribe(onNext: { n in
    print(n)
})
```

The expected output is:

```
query2() called
creating query() thread
2
4
1
3
5
```

However, the thread seems to be created a second time when it comes time to pull values from `odd`.

Actual Output:

```
query2() called
creating query2() thread
2
4
creating query2() thread
1
3
5
```

I looked at this code, and thought - ah I missed the `.share()` operator, since the `even` and `odd` are derived from the same stream. I did not add that in originally because I eventually merge those into a single stream `merged` to be subscribed on, and thought that Rx would do the optimization for me.

So I used share(): `let numbers = query2().share()`

The output still remained the same.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closure passed to `Observable.create` is called every time the resultant Observable is subscribed to.

The `share()` operator has a reference count. It will subscribe to its source when it receives a subscribe request, then if it receives another request *while the source is running* it will dispatch events to the second source as well.

The surprise here is that your observable completes before the first subscribe returns, so there is nothing to share. Note that when you call `onNext` inside your background thread, it *immediately* calls the closure passed into subscribe within that background thread. When you call `onCompleted` it immediately completes. It doesn't wait for the subscribe to exit to do these things.

The solution here is to make your `numbers` observable hot with the multicast operator. Pass it a ReplaySubject which will store the output and replay it to any subsequent subscribers. Don't forget to call `connect()` to cause the Observable to run its generator function.

Something like this:

```
let numbers = Observable.deferred { () -> Observable<Int> in
    print("called")
    return Observable.from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
}
.subscribe(on: ConcurrentDispatchQueueScheduler(qos: .default)) // this ensures that the block passed to `deferred` is called on a background thread.
.multicast(ReplaySubject<Int>.createUnbounded())

numbers.connect()

let even = numbers.filter { $0 % 2 == 0 }
let odd = numbers.filter { $0 % 2 != 0 }
let merged = even.concat(odd)

merged.subscribe(onNext: { print($0) })
```

Comment: Works great. It seems like if I were to do most of my programming in Rx world I would need to do multicasting a lot (which requires me to be very conscious of the code graph since this is explicit). Would you recommend getting into the non-Rx world as fast as possible by performing all the synchronous transformations after subscribing?

Comment: I've been using RxSwift for 6 years to date. I have never needed to use multicast in a production or sample app. The `share` operator is all I have ever needed (sometimes with a replay). The special case here is that you are spitting the stream and then recombining it using concat which staggers its subscriptions in time. That's a very unusual thing to do.